# How can i get the number of visible items from a filtered list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a list of 4 divs and an input field for filtering the list using jquery. What i need is to display/count the number of the filtered results on "keyup" function . 
I am using the "size" function to get the total number of the results.

However i 'm not getting the right number of results and i can't fix it.

Here's my code:

```js
var langMap = {}

$('#search-stores-box').keyup(function(){

 var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 var filteredWord = getLatinWord(valThis);
    
    var count = $('.storesList  .store-block').size() - $('.storesList .hidden-store').size();
    $('#count').text(count);

   
 if(filteredWord == ""){
  

  $('.storesList .store-block').show();
  $('.storesList .store-block').removeClass('hidden-store');    
    
 } else {
  
  $('.storesList .store-block').each(function(){
   $('.storesList .store-block').addClass('hidden-store'); 
     
   var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   text = getLatinWord(text);
   (text.indexOf(filteredWord) > -1 ) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    
  });
 }
   });
      
   function getLatinWord(word){
  return word.split('').map(function(character){
   if (langMap[character]) {
   return langMap[character];
   }
   return character;
   }).join('');
   }
```

```css
.results-box {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

.search-area {margin-bottom:10px;}

#count {display:inline-block;}

.store-block {
  width:80%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="results-box">Number of stores:
<div id="count"></div>
</div>

<div class="search-area">
<input placeholder="Type a store name..." id="search-stores-box" type="text" />
</div> 

<div class="storesList">
<div class="store-block">Apple Store</div>
<div class="store-block">Microsoft Store</div>
<div class="store-block">Motorola Store</div>
<div class="store-block">Nokia Store</div>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2a8v0xhw/81/)**

Comment: It took me a while to realize that your code adds the class hidden-store to all stores, no matter if the div will be visible or not. So $('.hidden-store').size() always is 4. That's why the calculation does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get count using `:visible`

```
var count = $('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length;
$('#count').text(count);
```

OR you can check store-blobk with no hidden-store class

```
var count = $('.storesList  .store-block:not(.hidden-store)').length;
$('#count').text(count);
```

check below working code snippet

```js
var langMap = {}
$('#count').text($('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length);
$('#search-stores-box').keyup(function(){

 var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 var filteredWord = getLatinWord(valThis);

   
 if(filteredWord == ""){
  

  $('.storesList .store-block').show();
  $('.storesList .store-block').removeClass('hidden-store');    
    
 } else {
  
  $('.storesList .store-block').each(function(){
   $('.storesList .store-block').addClass('hidden-store'); 
     
   var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   text = getLatinWord(text);
   (text.indexOf(filteredWord) > -1 ) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    
  });
 }
     var count = $('.storesList  .store-block:visible').length;
    $('#count').text(count);
   });
      
   function getLatinWord(word){
  return word.split('').map(function(character){
   if (langMap[character]) {
   return langMap[character];
   }
   return character;
   }).join('');
   }
```

```css
.results-box {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

.search-area {margin-bottom:10px;}

#count {display:inline-block;}

.store-block {
  width:80%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="results-box">Number of stores:
<div id="count"></div>
</div>

<div class="search-area">
<input placeholder="Type a store name..." id="search-stores-box" type="text" />
</div> 

<div class="storesList">
<div class="store-block">Apple Store</div>
<div class="store-block">Microsoft Store</div>
<div class="store-block">Motorola Store</div>
<div class="store-block">Nokia Store</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting but doesn't work. :( If you check my code above i need the search results number to get updated on "keyup" function.

Comment: it should work in keyup function, just replace your two line code to read count with my code. Please check updated post with code snippet

Comment: one correction, this line should be called at the end of keyup event handler otherwise it will not give you correct count

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfect. I ll accept your answer asap. Just one last question. If you load the code it shows no results until you start typing in the input field. How i display the total number of results before the user start typing in the input field ?? Once again thanks for your effort.

Comment: you can apply count logic once page load. Put it just before keup event handler. see my updated post

Comment: Letter A/a returns 3.